como hacer un mapa con datos responsivo en laravel 8
solicito de su ayuda con una recomendacion. En mi trabajo mi gerente nos pidio desarrollar un proyecto para unos invernaderos el cual consiste en "dibujar" la forma de los invernaderos y valores que se obtendran de cada uno de ellos (adjunto una imagen como referencia que se podria decir que es practicamente lo que se requiere se proyecte).
El tema aqui es que como no tengo mucha experiencia y menos en este tipo de proyectos no se realmente como abordarlo, eh realizado proyectos responsivos que aqui es donde viene el tema ya que se pretende que este proyecto en particular se pueda visualizar desde una pantalla gigante hasta una celular o una pc, lo cual es un realmente la consulta del post el ¿cual seria la recomendacion para realizarlo de una manera correcta?.
De antemano sabemos que bottstrap y css permite realizar dichos ajustes pero investigando hemos visto que se puede realizar una geogerca tipo google maps donde se establezcan coordenadas y con esto se evite distorcion de la imagen incluso al realizar un zoom sobre un elemento.
Hemos desarrolado un sistema muy amplio entrre 2 personas y todo esta basado en laravel por lo cual si buscamos integrarlo al mismo sistema.
Realmente no cuento con tanta experiencia en el tema de programacion, lo que eh venido utilizando recientemente es laravel en su vers. 8, con tecnologias blade,php, javascript, boottstrap auqnue no lo domino tan ampliamente como lo menciono.


Hola Christian, tu pregunta seguramente va a ser cerrada, porque la respueta estaría basada en opiniones, yo te dejo la mía, ya que las parcelas tienen lados rectos, tomas nota de las coordenadas de los vertices, y a partir de ellas dibujas (multiplicando sus valores por el zoom).
